# MySQL Make multiple foreign keys point one table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Im using MySQL with InnoDB
I have this (simplified) table structure:

Table Users:
 - id

Table User_docs:
 - id
 - user_id (should point to users.id)

Table User_dogs:
 - id
 - user_id (should also point to users.id)

so i made first 2 tables and added a foreign key like this:
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`worker_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

and its all were good, but then i've made a third table and wanted to do the same, but MySQL said that i can't have multiple contraints with same name.

So my question is:

should i rename my contraints to `fk_user_docs_to_user_id` and `fk_user_dogs_to_user_id`?

or (ofc better) - can i use my already created `fk_user_id` contsraint for both tables?

I'm sorry if this question is stupid and simple and asked many times, but i've an hour for googling and found nothing, i feel like this is simple basic situation that no one asks it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name them differently and you can't use the same constraint in both tables.

You may even remove the name and let mysql give them names for you:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (worker_id) REFERENCES users (id);
```